# R: How to extract a list from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider this simple example

```
> weird_df <- data_frame(col1 =c('hello', 'world', 'again'),
+                       col_weird = list(list(12,23), list(23,24), NA))
> 
> weird_df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   col1  col_weird
  <chr>     <list>
1 hello <list [2]>
2 world <list [2]>
3 again  <lgl [1]>
```

I need to extract the values in the `col_weird`. How can I do that? I see how to do that in Python but not in R. Expected output is:

```
> good_df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   col1   tic   toc
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 hello    12    23
2 world    23    24
3 again    NA    NA
```

Comment: `unlist(weird_df$col_weird[[1]])`
`unlist(weird_df$col_weird[[2]])`

Comment: thanks @EnriquePérezHerrero but can you do that in a clean, dplyr way? I want to be sure the data is correctlyy processed

Comment: You can try `weird_df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(col_weird = list(unlist(col_weird))) %>% ungroup %>% unnest %>% group_by(col1) %>% mutate(rn = c('tic', 'toc')[row_number()]) %>% spread(rn, col_weird)`

Comment: @akrun thanks but that's a pretty convoluted solution!

Comment: yes, then don't use it.  I didn't know that there were already some solutions posted

Comment: @akrun the actual solutions do not work with the current example...

Comment: My solution was based on the example you posted.  So, if the structure is different perhaps you may need to update the example

Comment: @akrun the example is correct. I am saying the solutions below are not correct

Comment: Based on the updated question, my solution still works on that.  Other option is `library(purrr);library(reshape2);weird_df$col_weird %>% map(unlist) %>% setNames(., weird_df$col1) %>% melt %>% group_by(L1) %>% mutate(rn = c('tic', 'toc')[row_number()]) %>% spread(rn, value)`

Comment: If you want a compact option, then use `data.table` `dcast(setDT(weird_df)[,.(col1 = rep(col1, lengths(col_weird)), col_weird = unlist(col_weird)) ], col1 ~ c("tic", "toc")[rowid(col1)])`

Comment: @akrun I would love to accept the `purr` solution, but can you please post that as an asnwer and explain what you are doing? also, can you write the code so that to obtain the final dataframe as shown (that is, keeping the other variables and creating the new ones). Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you collapse the list column into a string you can use `separate` from *tidyr*.  I used `map` from *purrr* to loop through the list column and create a string with `toString`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

weird_df %>%
     mutate(col_weird = map(col_weird, toString ) ) %>%
     separate(col_weird, into = c("tic", "toc"), convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
   col1   tic   toc
* <chr> <int> <int>
1 hello    12    23
2 world    23    24
3 again    NA    NA
```

You can actually use `separate` directly without the `toString` part but you end up with "list" as one of the values.

```
weird_df %>%
     separate(col_weird, into = c("list", "tic", "toc"), convert = TRUE) %>%
     select(-list)
```

This led me to `tidyr::extract`, which works fine with the right regular expression. If your list column was more complicated, though, writing out the regular expression might be a pain.

```
weird_df %>%
     extract(col_weird, into = c("tic", "toc"), regex = "([[:digit:]]+), ([[:digit:]]+)", convert = TRUE)
```

Comment: hummm very, veeeeery clean. im jelly

Answer (score 2):

```
weird_df <- data_frame(col1 = c('hello', 'world'),
                   col_weird = list(list(12,23), list(23,24)))

library(dplyr)
weird_df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(tic = unlist(magrittr::extract2(col_weird, 1)),
                toc = unlist(magrittr::extract2(col_weird, 2)),
                col_weird = NULL)
```

With the last changes: Note that now `col_weird` contains `list(NA, NA)`

```
weird_df <- data_frame(col1 = c('hello', 'world', 'again'),
                  col_weird = list(list(12,23), list(23,24), list(NA, NA)))

library(dplyr)
weird_df %>%
 dplyr::mutate(col_weird = matrix(col_weird),
 tic = sapply(col_weird, function(x) magrittr::extract2(x, 1)),
 toc = sapply(col_weird, function(x) magrittr::extract2(x, 2)),
 col_weird = NULL)
```

Comment: great! why do we have to use  `magrittr` here?

Comment: `magrittr::extract2` is an alternate to `[[`, it is used to make R pipes more readable.

Comment: cool, never understood what is the `[[` for. extract elements from a list?

Comment: When you code an R package you need to use NSE functions like `mutate_` and to @importFrom in roxygen2. Then it is useful to add @importFrom magrittr extract2.

Comment: hold on one sec

Comment: It seems this solution would fail with missing values. Do you have an idea? question updated.. sorry and thanks again!!

Comment: Enrico are you still there? :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with basic R, thanks to `I()`:

```
weird_df <- data.frame(col1 =c('hello', 'world'), 
   col_weird = I(list(list(12,23),list(23,24))))

weird_df
>    col1 col_weird
  1 hello    12, 23
  2 world    23, 24
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option to do with `purrr/tidyverse/reshape2`.  We `unlist` the 'col_weird' within `map` to get the output as `list`, set the names of the `list` with 'col1', `melt` to 'long' format, grouped by 'L1', create a 'rn' column and `spread` it back to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
weird_df$col_weird %>%
     map(unlist) %>% 
     setNames(., weird_df$col1) %>%
     melt %>% 
     group_by(L1) %>%
     mutate(rn = c('tic', 'toc')[row_number()]) %>%
     spread(rn, value) %>%
     left_join(weird_df[-2], ., by = c(col1 = "L1"))
```

Comment: that's really nice man, but what do you think of my solution? It appear to be even simpler

Answer (score 2):

well, I came up with a simple one

```
> weird_df %>% 
+   rowwise() %>%
+   mutate(tic = col_weird[[1]],
+          tac = ifelse(length(col_weird) == 2, col_weird[[2]], NA)) %>% 
+   select(-col_weird) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   col1   tic   tac
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 hello    12    23
2 world    23    24
3 again    NA    NA
```